# Image Processing on device android

Tags: android, image, image-processing

Want to create image of 1575px X 2125px in device android without OOM exception. The components data is available using json like image, text. Please help.

Comment: so you are saying at the moment you are getting OOM exception. put your code in your Q to have a look.

Comment: @Tasos No at the moment I am doing it on server side. I want a way to do it on device side. As doing it on server side I'm facing issue due different device resolution. Can you let me know any possible solution its a bit urgent.

Comment: Have a look around on the Net for android image libraries -- here's one called ImageMagick -- https://github.com/paulasiimwe/Android-ImageMagick -- http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php

Comment: @Tasos Thanks for reply. I'm using python as backend and using PIL for that the image creation part is implemented. The issue is only that the positioning that mapping image on device exactly same on server. Any hint will help me.